# SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: PosterDto.Id'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I try to post new item, following things are gonna happen.
In this aplication is used Mediator for API.

1. Find actual logged user,
2. Create new object of Poster (to reduce data sent to DB and also have some info about who created new Item),
3. Create new object of Item
4. Update DB

In Postman, there is an error:

```
"errors": "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
```

When I check terminal, there is more specific error:

```
SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: PosterDto.Id'.
```

PosterDTO:

```
public class PosterDto
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Item:

```
public class Item
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public PosterDto Poster { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new List<Message>();
}
```

Create Item class:

```
public class Create
    {
        public class Command : IRequest 
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public double Latitude { get; set; }
            public double Longitude { get; set; }
            public string Image { get; set; }
        }

        public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>
        {
            public Validator()
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.Title).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a title");
                RuleFor(x => x.Description).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a description");
                RuleFor(x => x.Latitude).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.Longitude).NotEmpty();
            }
        }

        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command>
        {
            private readonly DataContext _context;
            private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
            private readonly IUserAccessor _userAccessor;

            public Handler(DataContext context, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IUserAccessor userAccessor)
            {
                _context = context;
                _userManager = userManager;
                _userAccessor = userAccessor;
            }

            public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(_userAccessor.GetCurrentUsername());

                if (user == null)
                {
                    throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new { user = "Not found" });
                }

                var poster = new PosterDto
                {
                    Id = user.Id,
                    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                    Username = user.UserName,
                    Photo = user.Photo
                };

                var item = new Item
                {
                    Id = request.Id,
                    Title = request.Title,
                    Description = request.Description,
                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                    Latitude = request.Latitude,
                    Longitude = request.Longitude,
                    Image = request.Image,
                    Poster = poster
                };

                _context.Items.Add(item);

                var success = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

                if (success)
                {
                    return Unit.Value;
                }

                throw new NotImplementedException("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

ItemsController:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> Create(Create.Command command)
{
    return await _mediatR.Send(command);
}
```

Comment: Id = request.Id, I can' t see where request is declared. Pls post the whole code

Comment: Add your "poster" to thé context

Comment: @Romka What does it exactly mean?

Comment: @Serge Code is updated

Comment: Try to add the new "poster" object in the context posters table

Comment: @Romka But I don`t have Table only for Posters, because this object will be repetitive, cause one User can post more Items than only one. Is it necessity?

Comment: if you don't have a table for a poster you can't save it

Comment: I created table for Posters, add Poster object immediately after creating this object, but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encounter is related to entity framework. I guess you are using the code first.

```cs
public class Item
{       
   // Entity Framework will create a relationship between PosterDto and Item 
    public PosterDto Poster { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will create a relation ship between PosterDto and Item.
To prevent EntityFramework from doing this, add the attribute [NotMapped] to the PosterDto attribute.

```cs
public class Item
{       
   // Add NotMapped Attribute
    [NotMapped]
    public PosterDto Poster { get; set; }
}
```

Have a look to this article https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/notmapped-attribute